# How to set some items as already checked in checked combobox pyqt5 python

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to retain the items that user once checked, i.e. once user selects an item in checked combobox and if user again opens the userform then, he should be able to see its selection until new selections are made. Please help me in the same.

Comment: After exiting and reopening the application you need the previously checked check boxes to persist.is it the case ?

Comment: Yes, Right ! I want the values should persist in the checkboxes!

Comment: you need to implement a database here store the value when user submits the form and at application launch retrieve data from database and display accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I need to retrieve them on the userforms as well!

Comment: were ever you need the data you can retrieve them from the database